Unauthorized Error (401) with Microsoft Graph API: Limitation in Posting Messages to Teams
I am encountering an issue while attempting to send a reply via the Microsoft Graph API. The operation fails with a 401 error, indicating that message posting in application-only context is restricted to import purposes.
Granted API Permissions and types:
ChannelMessage.Read.All Application
ChannelMessage.ReadWrite Delegated
ChannelMessage.Send Delegated
Chat.ReadWrite.All Application
Group.ReadWrite.All Application
Teamwork.Migrate.All Application
User.Read Delegated
python code:
Generates access token
use access token to post message in team channel or reply to existing message
import msal

import constants

import requests

def generate_access_token(app_id, client_secret, authority, scopes):

    # Create a ConfidentialClientApplication with client credentials

    client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(

        client_id=app_id,

        client_credential=client_secret,

        authority=authority

    )

    # Acquire token for client using client credentials

    token_response = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

    if 'access_token' in token_response:

        # print(f" access_token = {token_response['access_token']}")

        return token_response['access_token']

    else:

        print("Error acquiring token:", token_response.get("error_description"))

        return None

def test_post_message_to_channel( app_id, client_secret, authority, scopes, team_id, channel_id, message_content):

    access_token = generate_access_token(app_id, client_secret, authority, scopes)

    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages"

    headers = {

        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',

        'Content-Type': 'application/json'

    }

    payload = {

        "body": {

            "content": message_content

        }

    }

    

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

    

    if response.status_code == 201:

        print("Message posted successfully!")

        return response.json()

    else:

        print("Failed to post message:", response.status_code, response.text)

        return None

def test_reply_message_to_channel(app_id, client_secret, authority, scopes, team_id, channel_id, message_id, reply_content):

    # Get access token

    access_token = generate_access_token(app_id, client_secret, authority, scopes)

    # if 'access_token' not in token_response:

    #     print("Error acquiring token:", token_response.get("error_description"))

    #     return

    

    # Define the API endpoint and reply payload

    url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}/replies'

    headers = {

        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',

        'Content-Type': 'application/json'

    }

    payload = {

        "body": {

            "content": reply_content

        }

    }

    # Send the reply to the existing post

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

    # Check if the reply was sent successfully

    if response.status_code == 201:

        print("Reply sent successfully!")

    else:

        print("Failed to send reply:", response.status_code, response.text)

# Usage

if __name__ == "__main__":

       

    test_reply_message_to_channel( 

        app_id=constants.APP_ID, 

        client_secret=constants.CLIENT_SECRET, 

        authority =constants. AUTHORITY, 

        scopes=constants.SCOPES, 

        team_id=constants.TEAM_ID, 

        channel_id=constants.CHANNEL_ID, 

        message_id=constants.MESSAGE_ID,

        reply_content=constants.MESSAGE_CONTENT

        )

Error Message Received:
{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",

"message": "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.",

"innerError": {

  "date": "2024-11-26T12:10:19",

  "request-id": "da3b9b53-43d3-407a-9608-9797217e4909",

  "client-request-id": "da3b9b53-43d3-407a-9608-9797217e4909"

}

}
}
I'm afraid we can't use client-credential-flow here for sending message to channel. Or is there another way around this that does not require user sign in.

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

Refer this SO thread of Prasad-MSFT

Application permissions only supports for migration,So it is not possible to send message with application permission, For that need to use of delegated flows like authorization code to generate access token. Refer this MsDoc

Initially, I got same error, When I try to POST message using application permission.


Note: Application permissions support only for  migration

So it is not possible to send message with application permission, For that need to switch for delegated flows like authorization code flow to generate access token.Refer this  MsDoc
To resolve this error you need to switch to delegated flow like authorization_code flow.
Registered Microsoft Entra ID Application and granted delegated type API Permission  ChannelMessage.Send like below:

Use below Python script:
import msal
import requests

# Replace with your actual values
client_id = "YOUR CLIENT ID"
client_secret = "YOUR CLIENT SECRET"  # Add your client secret here
tenant_id = "YOUR TENANT ID"
team_id = "YOUR TEAM ID"  # Replace with your Team ID
channel_id = "YOUR CHANNEL ID"  # Replace with your Channel ID
redirect_uri = "YOUR REDIRECT URI"  # Redirect URI as registered in your app

# Define the authority URL and scope
authority_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/ChannelMessage.Send"]

# Initialize the MSAL Confidential Client Application for Authorization Code Flow
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,  # Add the client secret here
    authority=authority_url
)

# Step 1: Generate authorization URL and navigate the user to sign in
auth_url = app.get_authorization_request_url(scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
print(f"Please go to the following URL to log in:\n{auth_url}")

# Step 2: After login, you'll get redirected to your redirect URI with a code in the URL.
# Example: YOUR REDIRECT URI?code=YOUR_AUTH_CODE
authorization_code = input("Enter the authorization code from the redirected URL: ")

# Step 3: Exchange the authorization code for an access token
token_response = app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
    authorization_code,
    scopes=scopes,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri
)

if "access_token" in token_response:
    access_token = token_response["access_token"]
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}

    # Step 4: Send the message to the Teams channel
    message_content = "Hello, this is a test message sent via the Microsoft Graph API."

    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages"
    payload = {
        "body": {
            "content": message_content
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Message posted successfully!")
        print(response.json())  # Print the response, which contains details about the posted message
    else:
        print(f"Failed to post message. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

else:
    print("Error acquiring access token:", token_response.get("error_description"))


Get authorization_code from browser:

Response:

References:
Application type permission only suports migration
sendChatMessage
SO Thread By Prasad-MSFT

Thank you @Pratik. I actually started with the delegated flow and it required entering the user credentials each time the code ran. Meanwhile, I need this to be part of a series of automated processes.

It is not possible with application type permission, As an alternate approach  create a migration team and channel to use application permissions and client credential flow. Refer this SO Thread by Rukmini

@Emmanuel Any update on issue?
